# IndexError: list index out of range (I think issue with split(',') in python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

I'm totally new to python. I'm reading two sensor (temperature and microphone) values from Arduino UNO. The data format is like 25.3,392.9 (temperature value and microphone value respectively). The data I get through serial communication is stored in a string called "DataArray". Whenever I try to output DataArray[1], it gives me an error.

```
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from drawnow import *
from tkinter import *

arduinoData = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodemFD121', 9600)

while True:
  while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
    pass

  DataString = arduinoData.readline()

  DataArray = DataString.decode().split(',')


  print(DataArray[1])
```

This is what I get from inserting

```
print(DataArray)
```

Output:

```
['21.48', '392.00\n'] 
['\r\n']
```

Comment: you should `print(DataArray)` and see what it actually looks like

Comment: The error means there's only one element in `DataArray`, which means there's no comma in `DataString`. Try printing it to see what it really contains.

Comment: What is the value of `DataString`? Are you aware that `[1]` gives you the second array element?

Comment: @DietrichEpp I think he's trying to get the microphone value, which should be the second element.

Comment: Fix the code indentation in the question. I suspect everything is supposed to be inside the `while True:` loop.

Comment: @ryugie This is what I get after print(DataArray) 
['21.48', '392.00\n']
['\r\n']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. There was a little bit problem in Arduino code. Arduino was providing the result like this [float,float\n] which was causing problem. After removing "\n", the problem get solved and the python code is working flwaless. I'm able to print(DataArray[1]) now.

Answer (score 1):

> This is what I get after print(DataArray) ['21.48', '392.00\n']
>   ['\r\n']

There's your problem: the second `DataArray` has only one element, the string '\r\n', which would be `DataArray[0]`.  Subscript 1 is out of range.

Comment: But print(DataArray[0]) is giving me just the value of one sensor.

Comment: The result you listed form the `print` statement is two separate lists; I took this as the output on successive iterations of your loop.  If this is not the case, please correct that comment, and edit the proper result into your question.  It's hard to give you a complete answer when we keep getting incomplete data.

Answer (score 0):

python arrays start at index '0', zero relative (indexes are 0,1,2, etc). This reflects offset from the start of the array, the first item is always offset of 0.

so if you just have one result it is in DataArray[0]. Try printing that.

Comment: I already know about this. DataArray[0] is giving me just one sensor value i.e 25.9

Comment: of course, sorry I missed that. Your result is multi-dimensional, the first item is a tuple. Python decodes into tuple arrays (look up 'tuple' if you have not used them before). So try DataArray[0][0] and DataArray[0][1] to access both items in the first entry.

Comment: Still not solved. Only displaying 3 and 9 which is quite strange for me.